# I am using Eclipse, why doesn't #include queue work?

Tags: c++, eclipse, queue

I am currently coding in c++, and I am trying to create a queue. Unfortunately, Eclipse is giving me errors whenever I attempt to do create a queue. Eclipse seems to be the only IDE that's giving me errors.

```
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
queue<s>q;
```

The error given is that: 'queue' could not be resolved.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does it work better is you say `std::queue`? Otherwise, could you quote the exact error you get?

Comment: Let me introduce you to the concept of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It's a concept that will greatly assist you here.

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the error. Telling us what you did doesn't really help us to notice if you did it correctly.

Comment: Know that errors given by your IDE does *not* equal errors given by the *actual compiler*.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ standard library all functions and classes are located in the `std` namespace.

So after including the required file, you have to specifying that you are using the `queue` from the `std` namespace which is:

```
 std::queue<s> q;
```

If you are going to use the `queue` class often, then it is usefull to bring in `queue` into your scope with:

```
using std::queue;
```

then everywhere in the scope it can be used:

```
queue<s> q;
```

Refrence: [C++ Refrence: namespace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace)